# ASN.1/SMI comment syntax on ANTLR 3

Tags: antlr, antlr3

On ANTLR 2, the comment syntax is like this,

```
// Single-line comments
SL_COMMENT
    : (options {warnWhenFollowAmbig=false;} 
    : '--'(  { LA(2)!='-' }? '-'    |   ~('-'|'\n'|'\r'))*  ( (('\r')? '\n') { newline(); }| '--') )
        {$setType(Token.SKIP);  }
    ;
```

However, when porting this to ANTLR 3,

```
SL_COMMENT
    : (
    : '--'(  { input.LA(2)!='-' }? '-'  |   ~('-'|'\n'|'\r'))*  ( (('\r')? '\n') | '--') )
        {$channel = HIDDEN;}
    ;
```

because there is no more options `{warnWhenFollowAmbig=false;}`, the following comment cannot be parsed correctly,

```
-- some comment -- some not comment
```

Then, what is the possible way to define this SL_COMMENT rule for ANTLR 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across a solution finally,

SL_COMMENT
    : COMMENT ( ({input.LA(2) != '-'}? '-') => '-'  |   ~('-'|'\n'|'\r'))*  ( (('\r')? '\n') | COMMENT) 
        { $channel = HIDDEN; }
    ;

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I like to keep grammar rules as "empty" as possible. In this case, I would create a lexer method that returns `true` if the next two characters in the input are `"--"`. As long as this is *not* the case, match any character other than `\r` and `\n`, and repeat that zero or more times until an optional `"--"` is encountered. Note that I didn't put a new line at the end because there is not necessarily a new line at the end (it could also be a `EOF`). Besides, `\r` and `\n` will likely be matched by a `SPACE` rule which is put on the `HIDDEN` channel: so there's no harm in doing it as I suggest.

A demo:

```
...

@lexer::members {
  private boolean endCommentAhead() {
    return input.LA(1) == '-' && input.LA(2) == '-';
  }
}

...

SL_COMMENT 
 : '--' ({!endCommentAhead()}?=> ~('\r' | '\n'))* '--'?
 ;

...
```

And if you don't like the lexer members-block, you simply do:

```
SL_COMMENT 
 : '--' ({!(input.LA(1) == '-' && input.LA(2) == '-')}?=> ~('\r' | '\n'))* '--'?
 ;
```

### EDIT

A small, complete demo:

```
grammar T;

@parser::members {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String source = "12 - 34 -- foo - bar -- 42 \n - - 5678 -- more comments 666\n--\n--";
    TLexer lexer = new TLexer(new ANTLRStringStream(source));
    TParser parser = new TParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    parser.parse();
  }
}

@lexer::members {
  private boolean endCommentAhead() {
    return input.LA(1) == '-' && input.LA(2) == '-';
  }
}

parse
 : (t=. {System.out.printf("\%-15s\%s\n", tokenNames[$t.type], $t.text);})* EOF
 ;

SL_COMMENT 
 : '--' ({!endCommentAhead()}?=> ~('\r' | '\n'))* '--'?
 ;

MINUS
 : '-'
 ;

INT
 : '0'..'9'+
 ;

SPACE
 : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n') {skip();}
 ;
```

which, after parsing the input:

```
12 - 34 -- foo - bar -- 42
- - 5678 -- more comments 666
```

will print:

```
INT            12
MINUS          -
INT            34
SL_COMMENT     -- foo - bar --
INT            42
MINUS          -
MINUS          -
INT            5678
SL_COMMENT     -- more comments 666
SL_COMMENT     --
SL_COMMENT     --
```

Comment: I will check if this passes all the test cases I have created soon.

Comment: Unfortunately this rule does not pass all test cases. For example, if this line only contains '--', then it is not considered as comment by this rule. Therefore, it is still necessary to use ( (('\r')? '\n') | COMMENT)as ending.

Comment: @LexLi, err, no that is not correct. Either only `"--"` followed by a line break or `EOF` will both be tokenized as `SL_COMMENT`. I edited my answer to show this.

Comment: Hi Bart, thanks for visiting it again. It is still strange to me that in my test this failed. The full grammar is here, http://code.google.com/p/sharpsnmplib/source/browse/SharpSnmpLib/Mib/Generated/Smi_no_action.g. If you change SL_COMMENT to your version, and then test with this text "bytesAvailAlert       TRAP-TYPE\n
  ENTERPRISE   alerts\n
--\n
  ::= 1", and test against "assignment" rule, then the '--' part prevents this full rule from working as expected.

Comment: Well, all I can say is that what I suggest is correct, which you can verify yourself by running the demo I posted. You grammar looks odd though: it contains some extra colons (in the `WS` rule, among others) and you used the v2 keyword `protected` instead of the v3 `fragment`. Not sure how much that affects your parser...

Comment: @LexLi, I also see that your `COMMENT` is not a fragment, which is not good. Either make it a fragment, or remove it and use `'--'` in your `SL_COMMENT` rule instead. Lastly, your `C_STRING` and `WS` rules can match input in more than 1 way, which ANTLR *must* be warning you about. Those are quite a few things that are not going as they should go...

Comment: Thanks Bart. I think I just finished ABCs of ANTLR, and porting this grammar from ANTLR 2 to 3 is already a big challenge. I will try to fix any drawbacks in the coming weeks, and hope to clean up the grammar gradually. Your above suggestions are appreciated. Thanks again.